# How to get text wrapped with <br></br>

Tags: java, htmlunit

I wanted to get the text inside **break** html but this it's not wrap with paragraph just a text inside break. Division is my only identifier for this which is **"Msg"**. How can I get one of each element?

```
<div name="Msg"style="display:block">
     <b>
       HI! 
     </b>
         2017-11-30-15.28.09.133

     <br/>
     <b>
         123
     </b>
         abc
    <br/>
       Your number is 5.
    <br/>
</div>
```

Draft:

```
HtmlElement msg = (HtmlElement) page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@name='Msg']/text()");
System.err.println(msg.getTextContent());
```

Comment: There is no text inside a br. `<br/>` is equivalent to `<br></br>`.

Comment: What do you want to retrieve exactly ?

Comment: `<br>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/empty_element), so there is no such thing as `</br>` in HTML.

Comment: @AxelH I'm scrapping a data from that div. I wanted to get the "Your number is 5".

Comment: @ChrisMartin Yeah I know that. But that's how the structure is built by system that I'm scrapping.

Comment: Unless you put that into a new tag, or you know exactly how many `<br />` there is before, you can't find it. Your value is not in a `br` but between two distinct `br`

Comment: @AxelH Yeah exactly between those br. Sorry to confuse you. I just wanted to get the text inside the div.

Comment: No, the text inside the `Msg` div is "_Hi! 2017-11-30-15.28.09.133 123 abc Your number is 5_". You want part of tha only!

Comment: Yeah the text inside `Msg` div. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understood correctly you might want the code output as

> Your number is 5.
>   
>   <b>123</b>
>   
>   <b>123</b>
>   
>   <b>HI!</b>2017-11-30-15.28.09.133

Maybe you might want to try with StringTokenizer (the codes below will hit java.util.NoSuchElementException as the nextToken() call is forced, but hopefully it will become a general idea)

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
..
String sampleStr= "Hello <br/> there <br/>";
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(sampleStr);
System.out.println(token.nextToken());//You can use .trim()
System.out.println(token.nextToken());
```

Would this help?

Comment: String Tokenizer give me hints. Appreciated your help :)

Comment: Great, nice to know that this helps!